# android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION also gives permission to android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am testing android permissions for both camera and location. Surprisingly to me, I learned that when I give access to fine location, system also gives permission to coarse location. Is this normal? I first checked with Toasts to see the granted accesses. When I give access to coarse only, it shows that fine location permission is denied, which is normal. But when I give access to fine address, it also gives permission to coarse location. Is this normal?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var cameraResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<String> =
        registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()){
            isGranted ->
            if (isGranted){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

    //This time we create the Activity result launcher of type Array<String>
    private var cameraAndLocationResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>> =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()){
            permissions ->
            /**
            Here it returns a Map of permission name as key with boolean as value
            Loop through the map to get the value we need which is the boolean
            value
             */
            permissions.entries.forEach{
                val permissionName = it.key
                val isGranted = it.value
                println(permissionName)
                println(isGranted)
                if (isGranted){
                    if (permissionName == Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted for fine location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    }else if(permissionName == Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted for coarse location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted for Camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }else{
                    if (permissionName == Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied for fine location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    }else if(permissionName == Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied for coarse location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied for Camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val btnCameraPermission: Button = binding.btnCameraPermission
        btnCameraPermission.setOnClickListener {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
                showRationaleDialog("Permission Demo requires camera access", "Camera cannot be used because Camera access is denied")
            }else{
                // You can directly ask for the permission.
                // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.

//                cameraResultLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)  this for only camera permission
                cameraAndLocationResultLauncher.launch(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showRationaleDialog(
        title: String,
        message: String,
    ){
        val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("Cancel"){
                    dialog, _-> dialog.dismiss()
            }
        builder.create().show()
    }

}

I/System.out: android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
I/System.out: true
I/System.out: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
I/System.out: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this normal?

Yes. Most permissions are not set up this way, but this pair is. After all, if you can measure location within a few dozen meters (`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`), then by definition you can measure location within a much larger radius (`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`).